# Set default values by script?

Tags: unity, c#

Insted of Inspector, I want to set default values by script because there is `MeshRenderer`, a `RigiBody` etc. I don't know how to write this in script. These are not numerical values.

Comment: This can only be done in a standard way for prefabs. Are the game objects this script is attached to instances of prefabs? Otherwise, your best bet is a custom editor. Not regularly via a script like with numerical values, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the component is on the same game object as your script, you can do:

```
void Awake()
{
    Rigi = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}
```

This will search the game object this script is attached to for a component of the given type(and return the first one found if there are multiple.)

If you want something that's in the same scene as this gameobject you can use:

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectOfType.html

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think that will only get scene objects since assets are not active.

If you want something that exists as only an asset then it's a little harder. You'll need to use a combination of:

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/editor-CustomEditors.html

And:
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath.html

You could create a custom editor in order to use AssetData.LoadAssetAtPath(with a hard coded path). Assign this reference to a serialized field and it'll be available and valid in a build.

I don't recommend doing any of this. Just drag a drop the references. It has a lot of problems, but it's far better than the alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your script where you have method void Start(), add there your default values for properties, for example:

```
void Start()
{
     Pop = 10;
     Bolly = true;
}
```

Comment: This does not set default properties, this just overwrites whatever the user configured.

Comment: @KevinvanderVelden That seems to be what he's asking despite the question title.

Comment: In order to do that you must have all the references in your script to assign it initially.